# How long should I wait before animating the navigation bar in/out when the user scrolls?

Tags: navigation, web, animation

I'm currently working on a new design for a site and I've encountered a problem I've never found before.

I want to collapse the navigation bar up when the user scrolls down to increase available real estate.

Is there a standard time delay to wait before collapsing a menu?

Answer (score 1):

If you react to a user action more than 300ms later, it will not be perceived as a reaction to the action in the first place.

So in other words, there is no minimum, but a maximum of how long you can wait.

My recommendation would be to not wait at all: What's the value of keeping the menu bar while the user scrolls? If you make it obvious that the bar is disappearing because of scrolling down (by reacting <300ms), users can infer that it will re-appear by scrolling up.

Comment: I'm not sure the right thing to do is to animate the bar in and out every time the user moves a small distance on the page once they've already scrolled a little way down.  

It'd constantly be appearing and disappearing every time the user adjusts the screen position a little.

Comment: Agreed, maybe a scrolled distance is more appropriate to avoid that.